# Android-MPChartLibrary unable to override default "No Chart data available text"

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using Android-MPChartLibrary for showing a LineChart. Empty view for `LineChart` is showing "No chart data available" and "No data to display"[image]

```
chart.setDescription("");
chart.setNoDataTextDescription("No data to display");
```

I just want it to say "No data to display" but not sure why it is showing both.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you fixed it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What worked for me was putting this after setting all the chart data points.

```
chart.setDescription("");
chart.setNoDataText("No Chart Data"); // this is the top line
chart.setNoDataTextDescription("..."); // this is one line below the no-data-text
chart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me either. Something probably was changed in the MPChart library

Answer (score 2):

```
chart.setDescription(null);      
chart.setNoDataText("No data to display");
```

And after:

```
chart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mainLayout = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
mChart = new PieChart(this);

mChart.invalidate();
mainLayout.setNoDataText("");
```

You must `setNoDataText` for your `mainLayout` not for `mChart`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just write these two lines in the onCreate method.

```
LineChart line = (LineChart) findViewbyId(R.id.line);
line.setNoDataText("");
```

That's it. Your by default text no data available text is gone now.